# In MS Excel, how can you convert mm.ss into mm:ss?

Tags: excel, time, replace

**Is there a way to convert a time in the format mm.ss into mm:ss?**

For example, I have an entire column going down:

- 12.37,
  1.34,
  5.36

I want it to say:

- 00:12:37,
  00:01:34,
  00:05:36

I've tried using the find/replace tool on Excel, but since the values are formatted as "number" rather than duration, changing them ends up changing it into some kind of larger value.

Is there a way to just replace **.** to **:** and turn my numbers into a duration format?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=--("00:"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",":"))
```

Then format the output as `hh:mm:ss`

[image]